# ColdFusion Zero Byte Padding Java 1.6 vs 1.7

Tags: java, encryption, coldfusion, java-7, java-6

```
<cfset var strB = createObject("java", "java.lang.StringBuilder")/>

<cfloop from=1 to=32 index="i">
    <cfset zeroPad = zeroPad & URLDecode("%00")/>
</cfloop>

<cfset strB.append(arguments.username)/>
<cfset strB.append(arguments.password)/>
<cfset strB.append(zeroPad)/>

<cfif strB.length() GT 32>
    <cfset key = strB.substring(0,32)/>
<cfelse>
    <cfset key = strB.toString()/>
</cfif>
```

The key being generated is used for AES encryption. Here's the method for that...

```
<cffunction name="aesEncrypt" returntype="string" output="no">

    <cfargument name="plainText" type="string" />
    <cfargument name="key" type="string" />

    <cfset var cipher = CreateObject("java", "javax.crypto.Cipher")/>
    <cfset var system = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.System")/>
    <cfset var secretkeyspec = CreateObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec")/>
    <cfset var ivparamspec = CreateObject("java", "javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec")/>
    <cfset var b64 = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64")/>

    <cfset var result = ""/>
    <cfset var keyBytes = getByteArray(32)/>
    <cfset var iv = getByteArray(16)/>
    <cfset var b = key.getBytes('UTF-8')/>

    <cfset var cipher = cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")/>

    <cftry>

    <cfset keyLen = len(b)/>
    <cfif keyLen gt len(keyBytes)>
        <cfset keyLen = len(keyBytes)/>
    </cfif>

    <cfset system.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBytes, 0, keyLen)/>
    <cfset system.arraycopy(b, 0, iv, 0, 16)/>

    <cfset keySpec = secretkeyspec.init(keyBytes, "AES")/>
    <cfset ivSpec = ivparamspec.init(iv)/>

    <cfset cipher.init(cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)/>

    <cfset results = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes())/>

    <cfset result = binaryEncode(results, "Base64")/>

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfthrow message="#cfcatch.Message# (plainText:#plainText# key:#key#)"/>
    </cfcatch>

    </cftry>

    <cfreturn result/>

</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getByteArray" access="private" returnType="binary" output="no">
        <cfargument name="size" type="numeric" required="true"/>
        <cfset var emptyByteArray =
        createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream").init().toByteArray()/>
        <cfset var byteClass = emptyByteArray.getClass().getComponentType()/>
        <cfset var byteArray =
        createObject("java","java.lang.reflect.Array").newInstance(byteClass, arguments.size)/>
        <cfreturn byteArray/>
    </cffunction>
```

On my local dev machine (Mac OS X Mavericks, Java 1.6) this works fine and I'm able to encrypt with the generated key. However, on my Production environment (Windows Server 2008, Java 1.7) I'm getting error "Invalid key size". The key size on both shows as 32 and I'm flummoxed.

I'm currently updating my local dev machine to match the Java version on server, but I still can't think of what the differences are in such simple classes that would cause this.

Comment: Can you provide an example with literal values we can test idependently? Also, is there a reason you are generating your own keys rather than using something more secure like `generateSecretKey`?

Comment: @Leigh The API I'm using with this key isn't something I have control over.  These are the brakes.  Once the API method that is used with this key is successfully executed, the server provides a private key that is used in subsequent methods.  I didn't design it and I can't change it.

Comment: @Leigh I've updated the question with my aesEncrypt method

Comment: Okay. Are you able to generate a dummy/sample key, and post some test values, or is that all generated by the other party (ie something you cannot share)?

Comment: Also, I noticed the code does not specify a charset here: `plainText.getBytes()`, so it will use the default. If the default differs between the machines, it could cause different results. 1) What is the default for the two machines? 2) What is the code for `getByteArray` ?

Comment: 3) Is your server set up for 256bit keys? By default you are limited to 128, unless you install the [unlimited strength policy files](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/222.cfm) files. It still applies to 1.7. (As you can tell, the error could be caused by a lot of things. That is why I was pushing for sample values we could test, so we could try and rule out some of the possibilities ;-)

Comment: @Leigh The same encryptAES function has been in use in production with no problems.  The difference is that I'm just now implementing the method that requires the manually created key.  First it was a matter of getting the null padding to work (thanks again) and now it's apparently a difference in Java.  I've only now got my local dev environment running on Java 1.7 so I'm hoping I can at least replicate issue I'm seeing out on production.

Comment: @Leigh Updated with getByteArray function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42687/discussion-between-leigh-and-e-madd)